# add a button to a custom cell that displays another modal view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Inside a **custom cell** I have a **button** that I need to show **another view cotroller** in a **modal** way.
Nowadays that view in modal is shown when **tapping** the cell in **general**, through func tableView ... **didSelectRowAt**, but we want to do it from a specific button inside the cell.

**current code**: TableViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    if indexPath.section == Section.History.rawValue {
        let viewc = UIStoryboard.checkout.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: DeliverViewController.identifier) as! DeliverViewController
        viewc.deliveryId = deliveryArray[indexPath.row].id
        viewc.rateDelegate = self
        let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewc)
        present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**I want to pass that action to the IBAction of my button inside the swift file inside my custom cell class.** Thanks !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. You should try searching for an answer before posting a question. Searching google (or wherever) for `swift uibutton in uitableviewcell` turns up plenty of information to solve this.

Comment: Seems that your challenge isn't adding a button to a cell with an IBAction, because that's fairly straight-forward, but that you need to pass some information from your data source to the button, is that right?

Comment: Thanks for writing! I was able to make the button work inside the custom cell by following this [guide] (https://web.archive.org/web/20160730215620/http://candycode.io/how-to-properly-do-buttons-in-table-view-cells-using-swift-closures/)